# My function won't return any values or printing any output. Is there something wrong with my function? Any way to get it done?

Tags: python, csv

How do i return the value?

```
import csv
import Load

def SignUp():
    Found = False

    Player_Name= str(input("Masukkan nama pemain: "))
    Player_Birthdate = str(input("Masukkan tanggal lahir pemain (DD/MM/YYYY): "))
    Player_Height = str(input("Masukkan tinggi badan pemain (cm): "))
    Player_Username = str(input("Masukkan username pemain: "))
    Player_Password = str(input("Masukkan password pemain: "))

    while (Found == False):
        for i in range(len(Load.List_user)):
            if (Player_Username == Load.List_user[i]):
                Found = True
            else:
                Found = False
    if (Found == True):
        print("Sign Up gagal. Username telah digunakan.")
    else:
        print("Selamat menjadi pemain, "+Player_Name+". Selamat bermain.")
    return #I tried removing return or make it return Found and make the 'if' outside the function and both didnt work

SignUp()
```

Comment: Sounds like you're stuck in an infinite loop, you probably just want to get rid of your `while (Found == False):` loop

Comment: To add to Nick's comment - is it possible that Player_Username does not appear in Load.List_user? Remember, your comparison is case sensitive so capital letters in one but not in the other will result in not matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your List_user array doesn't contain the username you're looking for, you'll never exit the while loop. You could re-write the function like this:

```
def SignUp():

    Player_Name= str(input("Masukkan nama pemain: "))
    Player_Birthdate = str(input("Masukkan tanggal lahir pemain (DD/MM/YYYY): "))
    Player_Height = str(input("Masukkan tinggi badan pemain (cm): "))
    Player_Username = str(input("Masukkan username pemain: "))
    Player_Password = str(input("Masukkan password pemain: "))


    for i in range(len(Load.List_user)):
         if (Player_Username == Load.List_user[i]):
                print("Sign Up gagal. Username telah digunakan.")
                return

    print("Selamat menjadi pemain, "+Player_Name+". Selamat bermain.")
```